# Pandas strip function removes numeric values as well

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, strip

I have a dataframe which can be generated from the code below

```
data_file= pd.DataFrame({'studyid':[1,2,3],'age_interview': [' 56','57 ','55'],'ethnicity': ['Chinese','Indian','European'],'Marital_status': ['Single','Married','Widowed'],'Smoke_status':['Yes','No','No']})
```

Once I create the above dataframe, I melt it and apply the strip function

```
obs = data_file.melt('studyid', value_name='valuestring').sort_values('studyid')
obs['valuestring'].str.strip()
```

Though it works fine in the sample data, in real data it removes the numeric value as well. I follow the same code as above but just the data is different.

Please find the screenshots of before and after strip function

**output before "obs['valuestring'].str.strip()"**

[image]

**output after "obs['valuestring'].str.strip()"**

[image]

How can I prevent numeric values from being removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your column has mixed integers and strings. Here's a reproducible example:

```
s = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 'abc ', 2.0, '  def '])
s.str.strip()

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    abc
3    NaN
4    def
dtype: object
```

If the value is not string, it is implicitly handled as NaN.

The solution is to convert the column and all its values to string before calling strip.

```
s.astype(str).str.strip()

0      1
1    nan
2    abc
3    2.0
4    def
dtype: object
```

In your case, that'd be

```
obs['valuestring'] = obs['valuestring'].astype(str).str.strip()
```

---

Note that if you want to preserve NaNs, use a `mask` at the end.

```
s.astype(str).str.strip().mask(s.isna())

0      1
1    NaN
2    abc
3    2.0
4    def
dtype: object
```