# Replacing column values in a pandas dataframe based if it contains a specific substring

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python data science and started solving questions. I got stuck in one problem where I am not able to replace some column values.

I am doing problem to predict old car price based on number of factors such as Power, seats, model, make, manufacturer and others. For a `power` column, fields are having values like as shown in snapshot

[image]

Some fields are having values `null bhp`. I am trying to replace these null values to `nan` so that I will be able to fill mean in those values in next step but I am unable to convert `null to nan`

Below is the code I am using

```
data["Power"]= data["Power"].str.split("bhp",expand = True)
#This is to change bhp
```

and then I am doing like this

```
for i in data.Power:
    if i=="null":
        data.Power = np.nan
```

It is not doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting and iterating, just search for "null" and replace with [**`loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) in one step.

```
data.loc[data['Power'].str.contains('null', na=False), 'Power'] = np.nan
```

You can use [**`numpy.where`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to do the same thing, possibly faster,

```
data['Power'] = np.where(data['Power'].str.contains('null'), np.nan, data['Power'])
```

Comment: For the first statement i am getting error as "cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values"

Comment: This is working when I used with `na=False` but did nor understand it

Comment: @Nitesh The reason is because your column has mixed data types (such as strings AND numbers). String operations will return NaN instead of a valid result unless you specify `na=False`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573134/pandas-strip-function-removes-numeric-values-as-well/56573162#56573162 for a similar discussion.

Comment: Are you saying, str.contains converts every string to NAN? and that is the reason you used na=Faise?

Comment: Are you saying, str.contains converts every string to NAN? and that is the reason you used na=Faise?

Comment: @Nitesh No, only the values that aren't string will become NaN, but that's a problem when you are doing boolean indexing -- you don't want to have NaNs in a mask of bools (it causes indexing errors). Hence the `na=False`.